# Understanting what the syntax for {:.2} means in python

Tags: python, string, format

I am working on creating a linear regression model for a specific data set, I am following an example I found on you tube, at some point I calculate the kurtosis and the skewness as below:

```
# calculate the excess kurtosis using the fisher method. The alternative is Pearson which 
calculates regular kurtosis.
exxon_kurtosis = kurtosis(price_data['exxon_price'], fisher = True)
oil_kurtosis = kurtosis(price_data['oil_price'], fisher = True)

# calculate the skewness
exxon_skew = skew(price_data['exxon_price'])
oil_skew = skew(price_data['oil_price'])

display("Exxon Excess Kurtosis: {:.2}".format(exxon_kurtosis))  # this looks fine
display("Oil Excess Kurtosis: {:.2}".format(oil_kurtosis))      # this looks fine

display("Exxon Skew: {:.2}".format(exxon_skew))          # moderately skewed
display("Oil Skew: {:.2}".format(oil_skew))              # moderately skewed, it's a 
little high but we will accept it.
```

I am new to python, and the following code confuses me here {:.2}, please can someone explain what this part {:.2}

```
display("Exxon Excess Kurtosis: {:.2}".format(exxon_kurtosis))
```

Comment: A floating point with 2 significant figures.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `kurtosis` and `skew` functions are doing the calculation, while the `display` function is probably just some form of `print()` for that environment!

`".. {:.2}".format(x)` is a string formatter which rounds floating points to 2 significant digits

```py
>>> "{:.2}".format(3.0)
'3.0'
>>> "{:.2}".format(0.1555)
'0.16'
>>> "{:.2}".format(3.1555)
'3.2'
```

String formatting is exhaustively [detailed here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language)